# Displaying a JavaScript PopUp on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, popupwindow

I have a simple pop up window (with nothing in it) that will load with the 'onclick' event. How can I modify the following code to make the popup appear the same way on page load?

```
<head>
    <title>Popup box</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function showPopUpBox(id) {
               var e = document.getElementById(id);
               if(e.style.display == 'block')
                  e.style.display = 'none';
               else
                  e.style.display = 'block';
            }
        //-->
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="popupBoxPosition">
        <div class="popupBoxWrapper">
            <div class="popupBoxContent">
                <h3>Popup Box</h3>
                <p>Form will be held here</p>
                <p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPopUpBox('popupBoxPosition');">here</a> to close popup box</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPopUpBox('popupBoxPosition');">here</a> to see popup box</p>
    </div><!-- wrapper end -->
</body>
```

Comment: Call the function in `$(document.ready(function () {...}))`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){



            function showPopUpBox(id) {
               var e = document.getElementById(id);
               if(e.style.display == 'block')
                  e.style.display = 'none';
               else
                  e.style.display = 'block';
            }

            showPopUpBox();

}

</script>
```

Comment: This will prevent online handlers to call `showPopUpBox`.

Comment: You can see there's a couple of links with `onclick="showPopUpBox(...)`" attributes in the HTML. You've scoped `showPopUpBox` into load handler function, now clicking those links causes an error.